# validate email in rails after updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my user model, I have

```
  validates :email, :presence=>true,   
:format   => { :with => email_regex },
:uniqueness => true
```

In my controller, I update the email if a user chooses to change it like this:

```
@user.update_attribute("email","#{@new_email}")
```

However, it doesn't throw an error if the format is not honored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

update_attribute does no validations. use

```
@user.update_attributes({ :email => @new_email })
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that update_attribute skips checking for validation but update_attributes doesn't! Interesting.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes